# Import data from TFS to use in Telerik Reporting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am very new to using Telerik Reporting and my task at hand is to import check-in data from TFS for use in a report. I really have no idea how to approach this - all I am given is a URL for the TFS site that I need to draw from. I imagine the data will be called on from the controller when the report is loaded, but that is pretty much the extent of my understanding.

Sorry for the weak prompt, but I've been searching for a while and haven't found anything useful. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You basically need to call the TFS rest api's to get the data you need. Go to their documentation page and start there.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you mean you want to get changesets from TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get list of changesets from TFS (get check-in data from TFS). You can use [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets) to get it:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version={version}
```